# how to save current state of fragment

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin

in my MainActivity, I have a bottom menu and a FrameLayout.
each bottom loads specific fragment using code bellow:

```
bottomNavigation.setOnClickMenuListener {
        when (it.id) {

            1 -> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .replace(R.id.frame, ProfileFragment())
                .commit()

            2 -> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .replace(R.id.frame, MyCalendarFragment())
                .commit()


            3 -> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .replace(R.id.frame, ScoreFragment())
                .commit()

        }


    }
```

the problem is after traveling to other fragments, old fragment state will be eliminated,
how can I save the state of the current fragment and load it when I come back to this fragment.

Comment: you are creating new fragment each time, you can create array with yours, smth like `.replace(R.id.frame, array[it.id - 1])`, where array is array = listOf(ProfileFragment(), ...)

Comment: you should put the arguments that you want in a bundle. put a static method in your fragment for creating instance in retrive the arguments from bundle. don't just creat new instances. there are better ways to implement this. android supports buttom navigation now, you don't need to write code for it
[How to add a Bottom Navigation Bar in Android](https://medium.com/@suragch/how-to-add-a-bottom-navigation-bar-in-android-958ed728ef6c)

Comment: I try using arrays but I didn't work @AlexandrKolesnik

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure if this works out, but cannot comment as my rep isn't high enough. You could create the fragments lazyily and hold a ref:

```
private val profileFragment: ProfileFragment by lazy {
    ProfileFragment()
}
```

Because at the moment you create a new instance every time you replace the content.
That means your replace would look like this:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .replace(R.id.frame, profileFragment)
                .commit()
```